# Unable to use oracle 12_c with jsp getting blank pages

Tags: java, html, oracle, jsp, oracle12c

OS win 8.1
jdk 1.8
database Oracle 12_c enterprise
ide netbeans
I am trying to learn jsp
I have coded the following page and added  odbc6.jar file in database connectivity .....

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:orcl", "system", "mono");
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM person");
                // ps.setInt(1, qid);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                System.out.println("ID\tName\tPhone");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //int id = rs.getInt(1);
                    String name = rs.getString(2);
                    String phone = rs.getString(3);
        %><%=   name%><%
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am getting a blank page :(
The same code is running well in java se app.....
please do point me in right direction ..

Comment: Your printing to System.out in your jsp code which is not the page you are creating.  The <%= name %> should produce output on the page but I suspect that the code is throwing an exception and that is why your page is blank.

Comment: no stacktaces nothing just plain blank page

Comment: If i add another <%= "hello world" %> thats also working perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two changes at the very least.

1. Add `out.print("Error: " + e.getMessage());` to your catch block.  Your comment "no stacktaces nothing just plain blank page" makes me think you don't know that `e.printStackTrace();` prints to a log not to the page in the browser. `System.out.println()` also does not print to the page.
2. Replace `%><%=   name%><%` with `out.print(name);`.  Its messy and horrible practice to close and reopen scriptlet tags every time you want to print something.

   ```
       <%
           try 
           {
               System.out.println("ID\tName\tPhone"); //Print in background
               out.print("<P>ID\tName\tPhone"); //Print to actual page
               while (rs.next()) 
               {
                   //int id = rs.getInt(1);
                   String name = rs.getString(2);
                   String phone = rs.getString(3);
                   out.print(name); //Print without closing/opening scriptlet
               }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
               //Might not want to show the user the exact error in production though.
               out.print("Error: " + e.getMessage()); //print error to page
               e.printStackTrace(); //print error to log
            }
       %>
   ```

You also really need to start indenting your blocks better.

Comment: Its now giving an output Error:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the jar file for the oracle driver installed.